# WSO2 CEP 3.0.0 support of XPath 2.0 functions in the event builder

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I am currently creating an Event Builder in WSO2 CEP 3.0.0. based on an XML mapping.

I would like to use soma XPath 2.0 functions like tokenize in the XPath expression.

It seems that that the Xpath parser used by CEP is jaxen that does only support XPath 1.0 (which is far more limited...).

Does anybody know if it is possible to use XPath 2.0 functions in the Event Builder?

Thanks,

Eric

Comment: In fact I remark that you cannot do a lot with the XPath expression in the Event Builder.
Only an element can be selected via this pseudo XPath expression.
Even an attribute like /Song/@name cannot be retrieved.

Looks quite limitative to me or am I wrong?

Br,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

CEP 3.0.0 uses AxiomXPath which is based on jaxen (Axiom 1.2.11). So it will not be possible to use XPath 2.0 functions as you have correctly inferred.

I agree that this is quite limitative. However, the main consideration here was that WSO2 ESB has first class support for XPath and if any complex XML processing needs to be done, it can be done by the ESB first and then a Thrift(WSO2Event) event can be sent to run CEP queries on that event.

However, it might be useful to add more support for XPath in event builder. You can raise a JIRA or mail thread at WSO2 dev mailing list to discuss this further.

HTH,

Lasantha